# How can we trace push notifications being sent to the Apple APNS server from IBM MobileFirst 7.0?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are having some issues with push notifications being sent from an IBM MobileFirst 7.0 server to Apple's APNS server. Specifically, the push notifications seem to be sent successfully from the MobileFirst adapter, but never arrive at the target device. How can we trace this interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the trace string `com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.*:com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.*=all` to trace the inner mechanics of the push notification mechanism on the MobileFirst server. This should be specified either as a [WebSphere Liberty trace string](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21596714) or a [WebSphere ND trace specification](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254706), depending on which server type you are using.