# How can we validate sufficient network connectivity to Apple's APNS servers for MobileFirst 7.0?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are working with IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 and are trying to send push notifications through the Apple APNS server. We are not using a SOCKS proxy.

As far as we know, we have opened the relevant ports through an F5 load balancer from the MFP server(s) to the internet:

- `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`
- `feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196`
- `gateway.push.apple.com:2195`
- `feedback.push.apple.com:2196`

However, we are still seeing [tracing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865029/how-can-we-trace-push-notifications-being-sent-to-the-apple-apns-server-from-ibm) when sending push notifications of this form:

```
[10/22/15 9:43:01:362 CEST] 00000153 ApnsConnectio I com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl sendMessage Failed to send message Message(Id=7; Token=XXX; Payload={"aps":{"alert":{"body":"Test body","action-loc-key":null}},"payload":"{\"id\":\"XXX\",\"title\":\"Test body\",\"tag\":\"Push.ALL\"}"})... trying again after delay 
                                 java.net.SocketException: Connection reset 
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:208) 
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:134) 
        at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:260) 
        at com.ibm.jsse2.a.a(a.java:204) 
        at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.a(aq.java:684) 
        at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.h(aq.java:790) 
        at com.ibm.jsse2.aq.a(aq.java:371) 
        at com.ibm.jsse2.h.write(h.java:20) 
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:87) 
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302) 
        at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
```

(I have redacted the token and the Id).

I would theorise that the network connectivity is not set up quite correctly, but it is possible to [telnet to each of the above addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896870/27641) on the above ports from the MFP server, so on a superficial level, connectivity seems to be working.

Is there a way we can verify more deeply whether we have sufficient network connectivity to those servers to send push notifications, ideally independently of MobileFirst? I understand [a persistent connection is required](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) (*"...The provider connects with APNs through a persistent and secure channel..."*), and perhaps this is where things are not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be a continuation of the answer to your other push-related question: [Is 1-courier.push.apple.com needed for IBM MobileFirst APNS notifications? What is it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284509/is-1-courier-push-apple-com-needed-for-ibm-mobilefirst-apns-notifications-what)

Did you try to also allow access for 1-courier.push.apple.com:5223 and observed if things do start working now? I think you should allow it.

Comment: It's a 2-week turnaround to get that enabled. Yes, really. Hence why I'm asking the question... :)