# Is 1-courier.push.apple.com needed for IBM MobileFirst APNS notifications? What is it for?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

The IBM MobileFirst Knowledge Center [states that](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_setting_up_push_notification_iOS.html?lang=en) the following servers and port numbers have to be accessible for APNS push notifications to work:

- `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`
- `feedback.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196`
- `gateway.push.apple.com:2195`
- `feedback.push.apple.com:2196`

However, I have seen references in Apple documentation to the endpoint `1-courier.push.apple.com:5223` (for example, Apple's troubleshooting documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG31)).

Is this server and port required to be accessible by the MFP server (through a firewall) also? What is it used for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what is it for, but unlike the Knowledge Center - the tutorial does mention that the MobileFirst Server instance requires that address to be available for it: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/#setupiOS

Have you tried with and without it and observed any differences?

Comment: Ditto, as per my other answer - not quite that easy to enable/disable from the firewall I'm currently working with :)

Answer (score -1):

5223 is required only if the devices are connected over WiFi.

"To reach the feedback service, you will need to allow inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 2196. Devices and computers connecting to the push service over Wi-Fi will need to allow inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 5223"

Comment: Hi - thanks, but I don't think that's directly relevant. That phrase talks about *devices* (i.e. the phones, tablets, etc. themselves). I was specifically interested in what ports had to be open from the MFP server (i.e. the push notification provider).